# Tumblr theme doubling photos and videos

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

Photos are being doubled in posts that have 2 or more photos in them. Videos are also doing this. How do I fix this? (example [here](http://rwbyblake.tk/post/134605585932/laikyuu-if-ur-feeling-sad-just-know-that-lola))

Comment: Hmm...I have discovered that the bug only affects your desktop theme, not the mobile site, so this is definitely a problem with your blog theme. That at least makes it quite a bit easier to narrow down the problem. I also looked at the source (HTML, etc.) for the post, but I didn't see anything in that which would cause photosets to be duplicated like that. Weird...